# c++ releasing "_alloca" ted memory from stack

Tags: c++, alloca

I know that the behavior ot _alloca is to release the memory off the stack when you leave the function. Is there a way to release the memory earlier?

Comment: @Mysticial: `_alloca` is constrained by the size of stack — usually no more than a megabyte. Ill-advised as it is, I can readily understand the desire to reuse such a scarce commodity.

Comment: No, and also, don't use `_alloca`.

Comment: If your compiler supports VLAs (from C99) as an extension, then a block-scoped VLA will release when the block is exited rather than when the function is exited.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There's no point in using `_alloca` anyway- you can write a high-speed pool memory allocator that can allocate and deallocate faster from the heap, and with less size restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

no there isn't (excluding messing with stack explicitly, e.g. in an `asm` block) but you can use [`_malloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx) and [`_freea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8984a8h.aspx), if you need something like that.

EDIT: as BoBTFish notes: `If it was allocated on the stack, _freea does nothing` so this answer is incorrect wrt releasing the memory earlier. However, I think it is better not to delete it as it points to an alternative to `_alloca` which is somewhat safer.

Comment: The _freea function deallocates a memory block (memblock) that was previously allocated by a call to _malloca. _freea checks to see if the memory was allocated on the heap or the stack. *If it was allocated on the stack, _freea does nothing.*